# Getting value of pandas timeseries at specific time

Tags: pandas, time-series

Lets say I have a timeseries

```
2019-09-20 00:30:51.234260+00:00    4.63
2019-09-20 00:50:51.292892+00:00    4.40
2019-09-20 01:30:51.273058+00:00    4.54
2019-09-20 01:50:51.270876+00:00    4.44
2019-09-20 02:30:51.267385+00:00    4.55
                                    ... 
2019-10-30 22:57:35.003066+00:00    1.71
2019-10-30 23:12:34.965801+00:00    1.61
2019-10-30 23:27:34.976495+00:00    1.56
2019-10-30 23:42:34.984976+00:00    1.26
2019-10-30 23:57:34.965543+00:00    1.05
```

and I need the value at time `2019-09-20 00:40:00+00:00`. Assuming that the values are recorded under a change-of-value principle, meaning no interpolation is necessary, the correct answer would be 4.63. How would I go about that?

Just entering `pandas_timeseries['2019-09-20 00:40:00+00:00']` returns a KeyError of course ...

I was considering truncating the timeseries to after='2019-09-20 00:40:00+00:00' and then getting the last value, but this seems very unelegant.

Comment: Would be nice if you include an example notebook or the code that gives you the timeseries. This way we know exactly what you're trying to do. There are multiple ways to handle date / time in pandas, and it would help a lot if we know exactly which you're working with.

Comment: @Cedar the problem is that it is a giant project and it's not possible to get the exact timeseries without violating a nda. Would the above post not consistute a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `searchsorted`

Will return the position in which the thing being searched can be inserted while maintaining sortedness.

I assume your time series name is `s`.  I subtract one because you are looking for the position prior.

```
lookup = pd.Timestamp('2019-09-20 00:40:00+00:00')

s.iloc[s.index.searchsorted(lookup) - 1]

4.63
```

Otherwise, you can use `reindex` with `ffill`

```
s.reindex([lookup], method='ffill')

2019-09-20 00:40:00+00:00    4.63
Name: value, dtype: float64
```